# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I study web application with Spring. My development environment is

- SpringToolSuite (ver 3.9.6),
- Tomcat (8.5)
- JDK (1.8)

I write source like in the textbook and run that code, but error message  has been shown:

[image: error description]

The full message is this.

```
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.**
```

The source works properly, but after a few seconds, the following error message comes out.

If you know solution, I hope you let me know.

Comment: You should provide the code, that caused the exception (a [mcve])

Comment: Ah... thanks i don't know about that. next question i will upload with source.

Comment: Please don't wait for the next question - [edit] the existing one :) (don't forget to check [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) guide).

Answer (score 1):

This is because of application servers like tomcat caching your old application. 
Try to restart it.

Comment: thanks... likes your suggestion, i can solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Right button in your Tomcat in Servers, then 'Clean', and try to running again. 
As other users replied, the tomcat is caching the old application